# How to avoid repetition of columns of same type in database

Tags: database-design

I am building a database that will save entities such as: orders, cart, customers etc.

All these tables share some common attributes such as: a date, the user agent that was used to create the new element and the ip address of the client (I am tracking the actions of the user).

Would it be considered "ok" to create a single separate table that will store these common attributes instead of repeating adding it in all the tables that require it (it would be the same field types and specifications for these common attributes):

```
log_id | log_date_added | user_agent_id | ipaddress
```

Then the field `log_id` would be added in the tables orders, carts, customers etc.

My first worry is that I will have to make a JOIN operation on the log table to get the date of any order creation, cart creation, or customer creation.

My second worry is that the more the log table gets bigger, the more it will impact on performances when retrieving the date, user agent, ipaddress for any entity that requires it.

In the same time, I feel it would be very redundant to add the fields `date_added`, `user_agent_id`, `ip_address` in all the tables that need those information.

Any best practice recomendation on that matter is more than welcome, thank you

Comment: Are those entries related to each other or are they seperate, i.e. do multiple rows in orders, cart, customers etc. reference the same row? Within a single table or across table?

Comment: the are separate: one new log entry in the log table when the order is created, one new log entry when the customer signs in etc.

Comment: If there's no relation across or within tables you should add those columns to each table. When you actually need to analyze the data across tables you can `UNION ALL` (and you might need some additional columns from each table anyway).